# how will alternative to Split('sunset.jpg') in PHP shows output?

Tags: php

Please help me to find the answer for the following php code in 5.3.5 and above.

```
$file_name ="sunset.jpg";
if(isset($file_name))
{
    $exts = split("[/\\.]", $file_name) ;
    $n = count($exts)-1;
    echo $n;
    $exts = $exts[$n];
    echo $exts;
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
```

I know that split() function is deprecated and we have to use preg_split (or) explode instead. But my question here is how should I modify my code to get the output as just 'jpg' only. When I tried to use explode and preg_split I got the result as 'sunset.jpg'.
Help to find the result.

Comment: It's easy. Use the search box in the site or google. Both will tell you the answer. Seriously. They will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just explode the string and use last element of it:

```
$file_name = "sunset.jpg";
if( isset( $file_name ) ) {
    echo $exts = end( explode( '.', $file_name ) );
} else {
    echo "error";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$exts = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

See documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Comment: I wonder witch one works faster, this or explode?

Comment: Not sure but pathinfo is more accurate because it works on many variation of filenames including if you have sunset.jpg?someVar=value etc. it should still return jpg in that instance